# Apache 2.4.6: client denied by server configuration (PHP FPM)

Tags: apache, php

I found a similar question but it did not helped.

When I open a PHP file via `https://site/test.php`, the following error comes:

```
[Tue Oct 29 11:15:53.480855 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 5424] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /vhost_site_ssl
```

Virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName site:443
  ServerAlias www.site:443
  DocumentRoot /opt/web/site

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/privkey.pem

  ErrorLog "/opt/log/apache/site_ssl-error.log"
  CustomLog "/opt/log/apache/site_ssl-access.log" combined
  CustomLog "/opt/log/apache/site_ssl-bandwidth.log" common

  <Directory /opt/web/site>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /vhost_site_ssl>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  </Directory>

  <Directory /php5-fpm-handler>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler php-script
    </FilesMatch>
    Action php-script /php5-fpm-handler
    Alias /php5-fpm-handler /vhost_site_ssl
    FastCGIExternalServer /vhost_site_ssl -socket /var/run/sock_site_ssl.sock
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I suppose this error is caused by upgrading apache 2.2 to 2.4. I also read this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html but did not helped.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to attach te exact error page:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /php5-fpm-handler/phpinfo.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at site Port 80
```

Comment: Did you try only put 'Require all granted' ?

Comment: Thanks your response! Yes, but did not helped.

Comment: I think that starting with apache 2.4 the way to connect to php-fpm is now mod_proxy_fcgi : http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM and not mod_fastcgi.